# pygtk spinbox style: gimp-like

Tags: pygtk

In GIMP the spinboxes they use for brush sizes allow for

1. manual typing
2. up-down spinning

They also provide a bar that can be dragged which provides a nice indication of the range that spinbox can take.

Is this possible with pygtk?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use Gtk.SpimButton and Gtk.Scale:

https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkSpinButton.html
https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkScale.html

These are the GTK+3 version but you can also find them in GTK+2 but I strongly suggest not to use PyGTK2 since it's not maintained anymore, use the introspection bindings instead through PyGobject:

https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Projects/PyGObject

You also have a tutorial:
https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html

and the API reference:
http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/

http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/api/Gtk_3.0/classes/SpinButton.html
http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/api/Gtk_3.0/classes/Scale.html

Comment: thankyou, ill have a look into that. I was holding off moving to gtk3 due to a lack of windows binaries (they exist now) but since GIMP has it and GIMP uses GTK2 it had to be possible

Comment: Sure it is possible in GTK+2 too, the problem is that PyGTK is not maintained so any bug you could find it will not be resolved.